# Error in fortran when using the Lapack command "zgetrf"

Tags: fortran, lapack

I'm new to lapack and trying to find the determinant of an NxN matrix. I used the code from dualm.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/computing-determinant-in-fortran/

```
program lapackdet

  implicit none
  integer :: N
  complex, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: mat
  complex :: det
  integer :: i, info
  integer, allocatable :: ipiv(:)
  real :: sgn

  N=2

  allocate(ipiv(N))
  allocate(mat(N,N))

  mat=2
  mat(1,2)=1
  mat(2,1)=1

  ipiv=0

  call zgetrf(N, N, mat, N, ipiv, info)

  do i=1, N
     det = det*mat(i,i)
  end do

  do i=1, N
     if(ipiv(i)/=i)then
        sgn=-sgn
     end if
  end do
  det=sgn*det

  write(*,*) det

end program lapackdet
```

When using this code, the error:
"*zgetrf*", referenced from:
    *det* in cc8VZrbU.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: The error msg means that the linker is not finding the subroutine `zgetrf` that you call from your source code.  Are you including the Lapack library on your link command?

Comment: Note also that `det` is not initialized to 1.

Answer (score 1):

As signaled by @M.S.B. the first step to compile your code correctly is to link `lapack`. I used `gfortran main.f90 -o main -llapack -lm` and it compiled fine.

Moreover, to get a correct determinant, `det` and `sgn` must be initialized to 1, as signaled by @KileKanos. And the routine [`zgetrf`](http://www.netlib.no/netlib/lapack/complex16/zgetrf.f) of the LAPACK library needs `COMPLEX*16` : the real and imaginary part of each complex number are double precision.

Finally, here is a working code which computes the determinant of a complex matrix. It is compiled with `gfortran main.f90 -o main -llapack -lm` :

```
program lapackdet

  implicit none
  integer :: N
  COMPLEX*16, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: mat
  COMPLEX*16 :: det
  integer :: i, info
  integer, allocatable :: ipiv(:)
  real :: sgn

  N=2

  allocate(ipiv(N))
  allocate(mat(N,N))

  mat(1,2)=1
  mat(2,1)=1
  mat(1,1)=0
  mat(2,2)=0

  ipiv=0

  call zgetrf(N, N, mat, N, ipiv, info)

  det=1
  do i=1, N
     det = det*mat(i,i)
  end do

  sgn=1
  do i=1, N
     if(ipiv(i)/=i)then
        sgn=-sgn
     end if
  end do
  det=sgn*det

  write(*,*) det

end program lapackdet
```